# When <li> get Hover Change the out Div Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So when someone hover a `<li>` I need that my Div get his class changed.

How can I do This?

Is this possibile using only css or do I need to put some JS inside?

Edit 1: each li will have a especific id, and the div would recive the id as a class.

Comment: Is that div inside the li? Can we see a snippet of your markup? Changing a class is not possible with css only, but you can likely achieve what you are after with the correct css selector. It is just not very clear to me what you are trying to achieve by changing that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To assign a class to the parenting `<div>` element based on the ID of a hovered child `<li>`, first check for the hover and get the ID name, then assign it to the parenting `<div>`.

The following is a code that you will be able to use for several divs on a page, and it will reset the class names on leaving the `<li>` hover, by using the out handler of the jQuery method:

```js
$(".changeme ul li").hover(function(){
    $(this).parents("div").addClass($(this).attr("id"));
}, function(){
    $(this).parents("div").removeClass($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

```css
.changeme{
    background-color:#eee;
}

.changeme.firstli{
    background-color:#ffd;
}

.changeme.secondli{
    background-color:#fdd;
}

.changeme.thirdli{
    background-color:#dfd;
}

.changeme.fourthli{
    background-color:#ddf;
}

.changeme.fifthli{
    background-color:#ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="unaffected">
    <p> some other parenting div, not affected</p>
    <div class="changeme">
    <p>some text, nothing changes</p>
    <ul>
        <li id="firstli">we are changing our parentting div!</li>
        <li id="secondli">we are changing our parentting div!</li>
        <li id="thirdli">we are changing our parentting div!</li>
    </ul>
    <p>some text, nothing changes</p>
    <ul>
        <li id="fourthli">we are changing our parentting div!</li>
        <li id="fifthli">we are changing our parentting div!</li>
    </ul>
    <p>some text, nothing changes</p>
</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/svArtist/adq5dr68/

Answer (score 2):

I think you should to use JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("li").mouseover(function(event){
   $("#capa").addClass("class");
});

});
```

Comment: Okkay replace:  `$("#id").mouseover(function(event){
   $("#divId").addClass("class");
});`

Comment: @Lewis, this would create a buildup of classes: make sure the classes are removed when leaving a `<li>`, or use `.attr("class", ...)` to replace the class instead of just adding

Answer (score 1):

Go to your div style class definitions and add "li:hover" near the name;

```
 .yourDiv { font-size:14pt; }
```

then turn to this

```
 .yourDiv li:hover { font-size:14pt; }
```

Comment: This would be awesome, but each li will have a especific id, and the div would recive the id as a class.

Comment: you can add you specific ID before :    for example li#specificID:hover

Comment: @SerhatMERCAN You misunderstood the question (as did I at first): The parenting <div> has to change classes according to which ever child <li> is hovered.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the :hover property, that way you wouldn't have to change the div's class, which you can only do with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

CSS hover attributes can be used to specify how an element should appear on hover, but not how some other element should appear when the first is hovered over. Achieving behavior of that complexity requires a touch of JavaScript.

```js
(function() {
  var div = document.getElementById("parent"); // save a reference to the target div
  var lis = div.querySelectorAll("li"); // get your <li> tags
  for (var i = 0, len = lis.length; i < len; i++) {
    lis[i].onmouseover = updateDivClass; // attach the event listener to each tag
  }
  div.onmouseout = function() { // remove class when no longer hovering over div
    this.className = "";
  };

  function updateDivClass() { // apply class to div when hovering over <li> tag
    div.className = this.id;
  }
})();
```

```css
.Class1 {
  background-color: #df7000;
  font-family: Calibri;
  color: black;
}
.Class2 {
  background-color: purple;
  color: white;
  font-family: Segoe UI;
}
.Class3 {
  background-color: black;
  color: lightgreen;
  font-family: courier;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  Hover over a class below to apply the class to the entire div.
  <ul>
    <li id="Class1">Black Calibri with Orange Background</li>
    <li id="Class2">White Segoe UI with Purple Background</li>
    <li id="Class3">Light Green Courier with Black Background</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```